# Ionic-3 Can't find Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have just upgraded to `Ionic 3.0.1` so I can use `LazyLoading` , and since that I can't use my custom `Pipes` :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'StripHTML'
})

export class StripHTML implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value, args) {
    let striped = value.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, "");

    if (args != null) {
      if (args.split != null) {
        striped = striped.split(args.split);
        if (args.index != null) {
          striped = striped[args.index];
        }
      }
    }

    return striped;
  }
}
```

and in `app.module.ts` I have added it to the declarations :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ........,
    StripHTML
  ],
...
```

now when am trying to use it in the `html` template it errors:

```
core.es5.js:1085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'StripHTML' could not be found ("
          <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title style="font-size: 100%">
              {{ [ERROR ->]product.title | StripHTML }}
            </ion-card-title>
          </ion-card-content>
"): ng:///HomeModule/Home.html@33:17
```

is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: I have a similar error since migration : Can't find name 'PipeTransform'

Answer (score 30, accepted):

so I fixed this issue by making a `PipesModule` where I import my custom `Pipes` into, then import it in the page `module.ts` that I wanna use it on

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { StripHTML } from './strip-html';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    StripHTML,
  ],
  imports: [

  ],
  exports: [
    StripHTML
  ]
})
export class PipesModule { }
```

and then in the page | `HomePage` as an example:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Home } from './home';

import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Home,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(Home),
    PipesModule
  ],
  exports: [
    Home
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

and it did work fine , not sure if this is the correct way or not , but it worked fine, please let me know if there is a better way... thanks!

Comment: This works, but it requires adding the `PipesModule` to every `Page.module.ts`

Comment: @AmrElAdawy it seems to be the way Angular4 wants us to follow, not sure yet!

Answer (score 18):

What you need to do is just **import the PipesModule**(line 12 in below snippet) in to your every page.module.ts (i.e. home.moodule.ts) file....

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './login';
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoginPage,
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
        PipesModule
    ]
})
export class LoginPageModule { }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: What if you are using a pipe in a component as opposed to a page?

Comment: @EricG You can import the `PipesModule` in the `ComponentsModule` as well.