# Ionic 3, shared module for pipes, for lazy loaded pages

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

With ionic 3 pages can be lazy loaded using `IonicPage` and `IonicPageModule`. The problem is that these lazy loaded pages do not have access to pipes.

```
    Failed to navigate:  Template parse errors:
The pipe 'myPipe' could not be found ("")
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299610/ionic-3-cant-find-pipe) describes the issue and provide a solution. My only concern with the proposed solution is that it requires importing the shared module `pipes.module` in all lazy loaded pages.

Which kind of reverting back a nice feature introduced in angulr2 which is to import the pipe only one time in the `app.module.ts`.

I think there should be a better way by importing the shared module `pipes.module` in the `app.module` so all the pipes will be visible to all pages.

Here is the `app.module.ts`

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    PipesModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,

  ],
  providers: []
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Should not we use

```
PipesModule.forRoot(MyApp)
```

To make the `PipesModule` accessible to all lazy load pages?

Here is the `pipes.moudle.ts` file:

```
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
        BreakLine,
        Hashtag,
        Translator
    ],
    imports: [

    ],
    exports: [
        BreakLine,
        Hashtag,
        Translator
    ]
    ,
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was just like you trying to find the proper way to handle this, after some research I will say that is the way we are supposed to handle this because of the following.

From angular [faqs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-module-recommendations):

> Create a SharedModule with the components, directives, and pipes that
> you use everywhere in your app. This module should consist entirely of
> declarations, most of them exported.
>
> Import the SharedModule in your feature modules, both those loaded
> when the app starts and those you lazy load later

Also I found this ionic 3 [doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit), which provides some suggestions in how to handle components, pipes and services.

Comment: I had seen that Ionic document. The point is that my shared module is needed everywhere.  that is why it should be imported once in the `app.module.ts` to be visible from all other components.

Answer (score 3):

The new approach suggested to import pipes module in individual page module is better, because you don't have to load pipes when app / pwa starts, making app load faster using lazy loading.

Have a look at [this](http://masteringionic.com/blog/2017-04-14-lazy-loading-and-deep-linking-with-ionic-3/?s=2017-04-14-lazy-loading-and-deep-linking-with-ionic-3/) article for more details.

Comment: I want through this link during my search. I understand that this is the way.  I thought there should be a better way to less coding the imports everywhere.

Comment: what about with providers/services?