# Custom Pipe Ionic 3 | Pipe Not Found

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need help, I have problem with pipe in Ioni 3, I've been following this thread [Ionic 3 cant find Pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299610/ionic-3-cant-find-pipe) and this link [Ionic 3 Pipe Globally](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-import-and-use-pipe-globally/73729/3) 
But still no luck all i Get is The Pipe separator not work, I'm generating my pipe using *ionic g pipe separator* I use my pipe like this in my html

```
{{string | separator}}
```

my separator.ts (custom pipe)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the SeparatorPipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe for more info on Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'separator',
})
export class SeparatorPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
   */
  transform(value: string, ...args) {
    return value.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

my pipe.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SeparatorPipe } from './separator/separator';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [SeparatorPipe],
    imports: [],
    exports: [SeparatorPipe]
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

my page.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InfaqPage } from './infaq';
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    InfaqPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(InfaqPage),
    PipesModule
  ],
})
export class InfaqPageModule {}
```

Any idea why it doesnt work??

[image: Image Eror Pipe Ionic 3]

Comment: You really needed module files for pipe and pages?

Comment: @pareshGami i just following instruction from both link i provided , that i must use modules file for pipe , but still no luck cant find a way to call custom pipe in ionic 3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Step 1:  `ionic g pipe separator`

Here ionic generator src/pipes/pipes.module.ts => `Delete` that file.

Step 2: `Import` pipe in `app.module.ts` file

```
import { SeparatorPipe } from '../pipes/separator/separator';

declarations: [
    ...
    SeparatorPipe
    ...
  ],
```

Step 3: Just use pipe in page like

```
{{'STACKOVERFLOW' | separator}}
```

Comment: ITS WORK, OMG , I've been struggle with this for 2 days,,  thank's so much, but can you explain it what happen??

Comment: Cool.! Happy to Help.! When you use ionic 3 don't use modular concept because it causes errors when you create build in --prod mode. Ionic generates module but after prod flag not working why really don't know

Comment: aah i see thats why =-="its always causes error ..Thank's for the answer and the explanation

Comment: Using pipes in a module, the way `ionic generate` does, works fine even with the `--prod` flag.

Comment: Thank you! Working like a charm. Anyhow my editor Visual Code still throwing errors... "[Angular] The pipe 'reverse' could not be found". But it's working! :)

Comment: @FireVortex. Cool. Happy to hear.!

Comment: @Gene. Glad to help you.!